# Is there a way to prevent pyimage doesn't exist error when opening a new window in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Iv'e been working on a python assignment and and using imported images for a header on each of my tkinter windows. The first window produces this image perfectly fine (please ignore button formatting need to fix that later :))
[image]

Although when using the explore flights button to open the second the window instance this occurs
[image]

Heres the error snippet:

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-3-840b8d9f47f9>", line 114, in flights_menu
    bg_label = tk.Label(flights_men_win, image=bg_image)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3177, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2601, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage14" doesn't exist
```

Here is my overall code:

```py
import tkinter  as tk

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

from tkinter import Label, messagebox, PhotoImage, ttk

class Application:
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        self.main_window = main_window
        self.main_window.resizable(False, False)

        

        ## Login Window
        self.main_window.title("Login")
        self.main_window.geometry("300x150")
        self.main_window.iconbitmap('login_icon.png')

        self.label_usrname = tk.Label(self.main_window, text = "Username")
        self.label_passwrd = tk.Label(self.main_window, text = "Password")

        self.entry_usrname = tk.Entry(self.main_window)
        self.entry_passwrd = tk.Entry(self.main_window, show="*")

        self.login_button = tk.Button(self.main_window, text = "Login", command=self.login_button_clicked)
        self.exit_button = tk.Button(self.main_window, text = "Exit", command=self.main_window.quit())


        self.label_usrname.grid(row=0, sticky='e', padx=10, pady=10)
        self.label_passwrd.grid(row=1, sticky='e', padx=10, pady=10)
        self.entry_usrname.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.entry_passwrd.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.login_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.exit_button.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)


    def login_button_clicked(self):
        username = self.entry_usrname.get()
        password = self.entry_passwrd.get()

        if username == "admin" and password == "password":
            self.main_window.destroy()
            self.agency_window()

        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Login Error", "Please enter the correct username and password")


    def agency_window(self):
        agency_win = tk.Tk()
        
        # Set the title and size of the main window
        agency_win.title("Prog2 Travel Agency")
        agency_win.geometry("600x280")
        agency_win.configure(bg="white")
        agency_win.resizable(False,False)
        
        img = tk.Image("photo", file="agency_icon.png")
        agency_win.iconphoto(True, img)
        #agency_win.tk.call('wm','iconphoto', root._w, img)


        # Background image (You can replace 'background.jpg' with your actual image path)
        bg_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="agency.png")
        bg_label = tk.Label(agency_win, image=bg_image)
        bg_label.pack(fill=tk.X)

        # Welcome message label
        welcome_label = tk.Label(agency_win, text="Hi Davey, welcome to the Prog2 Travel Agency", bg="white", fg="DeepSkyBlue2", font=("Arial", 20, "bold"), pady=20)
        welcome_label.pack(fill=tk.X)

        # Button styles using ttk (themed tk)
        style = ttk.Style()
        layout = style.layout('TButton')
        style.layout('Blue.TButton', layout)
        style.configure("Blue.TButton", font=("Arial", 20, "bold"), padding=5, background="DeepSkyBlue2", foreground="white")

        # Frame to hold buttons
        button_frame = tk.Frame(agency_win, background="DeepSkyBlue2")
        button_frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)


        # Explore Flights button
        explore_flights_btn = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Explore Flights", command=self.flights_menu)
        explore_flights_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)

        # Explore Destinations button
        explore_destinations_btn = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Explore Destinations", command=self.destinations_menu)
        explore_destinations_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)

        # Book a Trip button
        book_trip_btn = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Book a Trip", command=self.trips_menu)
        book_trip_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5)

        # Exit button
        exit_btn = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Exit", command= agency_win.quit())
        exit_btn.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5)

        agency_win.mainloop()

    ### FLIGHTS MENU   
    def flights_menu(self):
        flights_men_win = tk.Tk()
        
        # Set the title and size of the main window
        flights_men_win.title("Explore Flights")
        flights_men_win.geometry("600x400") # Adjusted the size to fit the design
        flights_men_win.configure(bg="white")
        flights_men_win.resizable(False, False)
        
        # Header image
        bg_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="flight.png")
        bg_label = tk.Label(flights_men_win, image=bg_image)
        bg_label.pack(fill=tk.X)


        # Welcome message label
        welcome_label = Label(flights_men_win, text="Hi Davey, welcome to the Flights section", bg="white", fg="DeepSkyBlue2", font=("Arial", 18))
        welcome_label.place(x=140, y=70) 

        # Button Frame
        button_frame = tk.Frame(flights_men_win, bg="white")
        button_frame.place(x=200, y=220) 
        
        # Buttons inside the frame
        view_all_flights_btn = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="View All Flights", command=self.view_flights)
        view_all_flights_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        view_flights_by_country_btn = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="View Flights by Country", command=self.view_flights_filtered)
        view_flights_by_country_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        add_flight_btn = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Add Flight", command=self.add_flight)
        add_flight_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

        remove_flight_btn = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Remove Flight", command=self.remove_flight)
        remove_flight_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        close_btn = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Close", command=flights_men_win.destroy) # Using destroy to close the window
        close_btn.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=2) # Spanning two columns for the close button

        flights_men_win.mainloop()

    def view_flights(self):
        pass

    def view_flights_filtered(self):
        pass

    def add_flight(self):
        pass

    def remove_flight(self):
        pass
```

I tried using PIL imports for the images but that did not solve the issue. I assume that the image is being garbage?

Comment: Pass in `mater=<window>` when creating `tk.PhotoImage`s/ `ImageTk.PhotoImage`s (where `<window>` is the window that the image will be on). Alternatively you can use `tk.Toplevel` (instead of `tk.Tk`) for all windows appart from the main one.

Comment: Call tk.Tk() only once and only run mainloop on that window.

Comment: `PIL` doesn't use `tk.` prefix. Should be `img = Image("photo", file="agency_icon.png")`

Comment: Supra's comment is completely irrelevant.  Are you 100% sure that "flight.png" exists in the same directory as "agency.png" (which works)?

Comment: The error is caused by multiple instances of `Tk()`.  Use `Toplevel()` for windows other than the main/root window.